# Name for the volume "inside" a torus?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, terminology

If you have a standard ring torus, what's the name for the shape created by the empty space in the middle of the ring with the height equal to the height of the torus? For another explanation, it would be the resultant figure if you took a cube with height $h$, a cylinder with the diameter equal to $h$ and height equal to the circumference of a circle inscribed into one of the faces of the cube, and wrapped the cylinder around the cube such that the two faces of the cylinder touched. I apologize for the potentially confusing explanation, but any help is appreciated.

EDIT: the planar figure to be rotated is basically [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ymfwiohdrs)

EDIT AGAIN: I believe the jelly donut metaphor is accurate, though I couldn't find any reference elsewhere to "interior of solid torus"

Another Edit: After some more research, I have determined that it is possible a concave cylinder may appropriately describe it, but I'm not sure if it is plagued by the same issue as the hyperboloid (that is, the curves technically cannot perfectly fit the inside of a torus). Is this correct?

Comment: It's a volume, not an area. I suspect it doesn't have a name folks would know.You can invent one and hope it catches on. A picture would help.

Comment: If I understand your description correctly (I found the second description confusing, and "wrapped" is not very precise in this setting): I have never heard a name for this. One could describe this as the complement of a solid torus in its convex hull.

Comment: Are you describing something that looks like a pulley? No matter what, your figure is a figure of rotation, and you’ll do better by describing what the planar shape is that you rotate to get your figure.

Comment: I will echo the opinions of the above comments:  your description is very confusing.  Can you please post an image?

Comment: "Jelly" typically

Comment: @Lubin yes...is there a proper term for that shape?

Comment: I’ve never seen a standard term for this.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's the difference between the convex hull and the shape itself, I guess you could call it the *convex filling*.

Relatively appropriate for a doughnut.

Comment: In computer vision this is called the [convexity defect](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

Interior of a [solid torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_torus) sounds fine to me.

To address the edit: call it the jelly.

Comment: If my recollection serves, Hatcher calls that object a "handlebody", but I rather got the impression that the original question is about the "donut hole" in the middle of the torus, and not the "solid torus."

Comment: I don’t think that OP is talking about the pumped-in airspace inside an inner tube, but of course his description is not completely clear…

Comment: @XanderHenderson is correct...I am referring to the "donut hole"

Comment: I think handle body is too general, since it might have genus greater than 1. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handlebody

Comment: @LiamWilson The complement of the ring donut in the jelly donut? So the jelly then?

Comment: @LiamWilson You are rotating about -1 in that figure, right? Edit: ok, the figure is gone

Comment: The y axis is more appropriate; I just moved it to make the shape clearer. (oops when editing messed it up, fixed)

Comment: I'm glad you called it jelly.

Comment: @Chickenmancer I had to!

Comment: @Chickenmancer A genus 1 handlebody, then. ;)  I don't see that as being too general, though, since I am happy to refer to a genus 3 surface as a genus 3 2-torus.  That being said, I never refer to it as "jelly".  It is alway "Bavarian cream."

Comment: Bavarian, not Boston? :P I'd like to see jelly, Bavarian/Boston Cream, or something comparable as the technical name. We have amoebas, spiders, shadows, halos, rainbows, and so many other "normal" words that show up in various other fields. I'd be happy to see some food names show up!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a *name*, but it is a slightly more precise *description* of the shape you're asking for:  it's the region described (in cylindrical coordinates) by an equation of the form
$$r \le  a - \sqrt{b^2-z^2}$$
where $a$ is greater than $b$.  In this formulation, $b$ is the inner radius of the torus's circular cross-sections, and $a$ is the distance from the centers of those cross-sections to the axis of symmetry.  As Lubin mentioned in the comments under the OP, it resembles a pulley shape.  See the graph below.
[image]